# Two different databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Is it possible to have two different databases for development or production? One for Heroku and one for local development?

Heroku uses PostgreSQL but I prefer SQLlite for local development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it's totally possible - you can then use `heroku db:push` to push your local SQLite database into postgres running on Heroku.

*BUT*

And this is from personal experience, I've run into situations where SQL I've written is different between sqlite/postgres/mysql *AND* also gems I've used which themselves used findbysql which weren't tested against postgres and has then caught my out when I've put it on Heroku.

For the few seconds it takes to install postgres locally I would STRONGLY recommend you use the DB platform you are ultimately going to deploy to.

Comment: So according your experience you suggest to install postgres locally instead of using 2 different databases?

Comment: absolutely 100%. I also run mySQL locally for apps that I build that are deployed to that. ActiveRecord work great but if you stray from that and end up writing sql then IMHO you need to be using the DB you're deploying to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seriously. That was a great hint.